# datetime rendering in the admin forms

Tags: python, django

I have the following Model and ModelAdmin classes.  However when I view the posts in the admin list page, the `created` fields are rendered as `2010-03-01 22:15:18.494594`.  I've tried setting the `DATETIME_FORMAT` variable in settings.py, but that didn't help.  Any ideas how to control the formatting of datetime fields in the admin forms.

PS. I know I could write a method in the Post model, that does calls `strftime` on the `created` field, and render that method instead of `created`, but I'm sure there is a better way to handle this.

```
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)
  category = models.ForeignKey("Category")
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

#admin.py
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ("title", "category", "price", "created",)
  list_filter = ("category",)
  search_fields = ("title", "category__name",)
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to simply specify a date format for use in the admin interface.  You do have other options though.  Take a look [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).  According to the documentation the list of columns on the list page can include the name of a field (or simply property if I remember correctly), a callable (taking the model object as an argument), the name of a callable on the class itself that takes a model object as an argument, or the name of an instance method on the class.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Answer (score 0):

Odd, on my admin lists the dates are displayed like this by default:

> Feb. 28, 2010, 12:25 p.m.

Have you set your locale information in settings.py?

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
```

Comment: yeah I have those 3 settings defined in my settings.py